# Finding a column value which has no entry in another table

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join, rdbms

I have 2 tables Customer and Order. Their structure are -

**Customer Table**

```
CustomerId
CustomerName
```

**Order**

```
OrderId CustomerId OrderDate
```

Now, one customer cann have multiple orders in order table.

I want to find list of all customers who have never placed an order i.e., they dont have any entry in order table.

I know i have to use left join but am not able to completely figure out.

Comment: Note that `order` is a reserved word in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

I actually prefer using exists here:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Customer c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `Order` o WHERE o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId);
```

If you really wanted to use a join, then use a left anti-join:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN `Order` o ON c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
WHERE o.CustomerId IS NULL;
```

The check in the `WHERE` clause asserts that a given matching customer in fact did not join to any order records.

Note that `ORDER` is a reserved MySQL keyword, and so must be placed into backticks if you want to use it as a table name in MySQL.  In general you should avoid naming your database objects using reserved keywords.

Comment: I would add a LIMIT 1 to the NOT EXISTS subquery to make it perform even faster.

Comment: @yg-dba And I _wouldn't_ do that, because `NOT EXISTS` needs to scan the entire table in the subquery regardless to make the assertion.

Comment: My point is that MySQL wont stop searching after it finds 1 row if you dont put the LIMIT 1 in the subquery.  It will find all of them, and then return to the outer query when it completes.  For a NOT EXISTS, if it finds one, it completed its task.  We dont need to find any others.

Comment: I disagree with your suggestion, and `LIMIT` is not needed here.  MySQL _must_ scan the entire table, regardless, to assert not exists.  For the exists case, it will already stop as soon as it finds the first match.

Comment: To clarify my point:  It will look at the entire table - probably using an index.  My point is that MySQL will return as many rows as exists if you dont put the LIMIT 1 in the subquery.  It will find all of them, and then return X # of rows to the outer query when it completes.  For a NOT EXISTS, it only needs to return one row.  We dont need to return any others.  For a large table in the subquery, it can impact the performance.  In the above example, probably not much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NOT IN operator to check whether specific CustomerId is not existing in the orders table:

```
SELECT CustomerId, CustomerName
FROM customers
WHERE CustomerId NOT IN(
        SELECT CustomerId
        FROM orders
);
```

Alternatively you can do practically the same with the NOT EXISTS operator like this:

```
SELECT CustomerId, CustomerName
FROM customer
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM orders
        WHERE customer.CustomerId = orders.CustomerId
);
```

Which is better? It matters only when your dataset get really large. If that happends, just test.

Comment: This will return every row in the orders table, and wont perform as well once the table grows. A better solution is the NOT EXISTS filtering on the customerId in the outer query which uses an index.